# Running Tinymce multiple ajax calls issue

Tags: ajax, tinymce

I have been sending multiple ajax calls from a single page and trying to load TinyMCE with each ajax call. But TinyMCE loads only the first time.

The code I have been using after AJAX success:

```
 success: function(html) {
   $('#showmail').html(html);
   $(".mceSimple").each(function(){
   tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'elm1');
   tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl",true, 'elm1');
       });
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to shut down tinymce correctly before reinitializing an editor with the same id a second time.

To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
```